# ¿Como hago un puente de red en Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu

llevo tiempo intentando conseguir interconexión entre host y guest [ubuntu18.04 - kvm qemu] porque estoy preconfigurando un webserver y quiero usar el invitado como banco de pruebas. Total, que no puedo avanzar mucho porque el guest si tiene acceso al host pero no al revés.

Buscando he leído que debo crear un puente, y para ello modificar /etc/networ/interfaces de la siguiente forma(Así es como lo he dejado):

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#a partir de aqui esta lo nuevo
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.1.37
network 192.168.1.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
bridge_ports enp4s0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

por supuesto en todos los tutoriales mencionan eth0, sin embargo en ubuntu no existe y en su lugar está enp4s0.

Curiosamente, después de reiniciar el servicio de red

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

al comprobar los cambios con ifconfig -a... no aparece ningún cambio y se ve tal que así.

```
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.37  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::dd0b:4362:2668:e119  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether da:01:3a:03:c0:67  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 365643  bytes 484283142 (484.2 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 177556  bytes 16509811 (16.5 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
    RX packets 2566  bytes 247445 (247.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2566  bytes 247445 (247.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:7f:cc:c1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 83  bytes 5750 (5.7 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 57  bytes 5832 (5.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 52:54:00:7f:cc:c1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Se suponía que enp4s0 debía perder su IP y aparece br0 con la IP de mi host, pero br0 ni aparece. Si abro virt-manager, en el apartado de red de cada maquina me reconoce un nuevo modo de puente br0 sobre enp4s0, sin embargo al arrancar la maquina me dice que no existe el dispositivo br0.

Llevo un semana y me estoy frustrando demasiado, no encuentro ningún tutorial sobre el tema(mencionando ubuntu 18.04) si quiera que sepa que en ubuntu no existe eth0. Y los pocos que quizá lo mencionan, siguiendo sus pasos da igual, porque br0 nunca llega a crearse. Os estaré muy agradecido si sabéis decirme donde me estoy perdiendo.

PD: tengo el paquete bridge-utils instalado y actualizado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno finalmente encontré una pista y gracias a ella he resuelto el problema.

Resulta que ubuntu 18.04(creo de hecho que un par de versiones mas atrás tambien) gestiona las redes con netplan, por lo que los típicos dispositivos nombrados como eth0, etc los renombra de otro modo y el mismo se encarga de escribir sobre los archivos de configuración. Por eso mismo ningun tutorial terminaba de funcionar y terminaba por haber conflictos. No soy un experto en la materia(de serlo no hubiera tenido este problema) pero es lo que he sacado en claro.

Al lio:

hay que trabajar con un archivo yaml, netplan comprueba la sintaxis y ella se encarga de hacer los cambios en la configuracion de red. Los pasos serian así de sencillos:

Importante comprobar cuales son nuestros dispositivos. Con el comando ifconfig por ejemplo podremos ver cual seria el equivalente a eth0, en mi caso es enp4s0.

pasamos a modificar el fichero /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml con algún editor tipo nano o vim. es posible que el fichero final se llame distinto en tu sistema.

```
vim /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

nos aparecerá algo así:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Nosotros solo tendremos que añadir unas "pocas" lineas que definirán el puente y la conexión. Debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

  ethernets:
          enp4s0:
                  dhcp4: no
                  dhcp6: no
  bridges:
          br0:
                  interfaces: [enp4s0]
                  dhcp4: no
                  dhcp6: no
                  addresses:
                          - 192.168.1.85/24
                  gateway4: 192.168.1.1
                  nameservers:
                        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

(tened en cuenta de que en mi caso he decidido usar dirección estática, pero podéis ahorraros un par de lineas usando el modo dhcp)

Por ultimo nos quedan por conocer 3 comandos
sudo netplan try
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply

Con el primero nos sobra, pues primero hace una comprobación de la sintaxis y después prueba la conexión dándote margen para probarla y guardar los cambios.

y...
fin(aleluya)